# Mule agent installation and registration with a new server into MMC

Tags: mule

I have installed MMC (trial version) on Windows 7 and the Agent on a virtual machine (Ubuntu).

For the agent installation I did exactly the same thing as this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvxcC_9ZAbM but when I try to add my server with MMC I get this error:

> Could not register server: The server 192.168.109.128 failed to respond

Questions:

1. How can I test that the Mule Agent is successfully installed?
2. Is it possible to test Mule between my local machine and a virtual
   machine (this is what I'm trying to do but it's not working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Assuming you have kept the default settings, run `telnet 192.168.109.128 7777`. If you can connect, it means the agent is running well. If you can not connect, it doesn't necessarily mean the agent is not running but it can be a communication issue with your Ubuntu VM (like for example, a firewall blocking the connection).
2. Yes, that should work just fine, granted that you have control of the ports that are exposed by the Ubuntu VM.

Reference material: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Setting+Up+MMC-Mule+ESB+Communications

Comment: thank you for replying, I tried telnet telnet 192.168.109.128 7777 i get telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
then I disabled the firewall so i get this Connected to 192.168.109.128.
but for adding a server its not working i'm wondering if  I missed something while  installing the agent.

Comment: It's hard to tell without having a complete check list of everything you've done when installing the agent. In any case, I believe I have answered your two questions so please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution for this.

I created 4 servers on VirtualBox.
Each Server has Mule and MMC installed in it.

On one server I ran both Mule and MMC and on rest Mule only.

Note to be taken here is to first check

```
MULE_HOME/.mule/AGENT_NAME/truststore.jks
```

if it is there just remove it before starting Mule.

For full detailed information you can follow this blog

http://nikhil-bangar.blogspot.in/2016/08/mule-agent-installation-and_22.html

So as mule started on each server, go to your MMC Console and click on add server and provide related URI to the input.

Here is a snippet of configuration I did on my local machine.

[image]